# How to filter js object array based on multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I have the following js array:

```
var arr= [{id: "123", name: "Foo"},
          {id: "123", name: "Bar"},
          {id: "345", name: "Foo"},
          {id: "678", name: "FooBar"}
         ];
```

I have an onclick event where I get the id and name of the clicked element.

```
var name = $( this ).data('name');
var id = $( this ).data('id');
```

And this is the function I'm using to remove the elements from the array.

```
arr = arr.filter( function(elem) { 
                                 return elem.id != id 
                                 && elem.name != name;
                                 });
```

If I use just the id or just the name in the filter function it works, but together they don't work. If the clicked item had id-123 and name-Foo then all elements (that have either id-123 or name-Foo) are removed and I'm left with

```
var arr= [{id: "678", name: "FooBar"}
         ];
```

and I need just the one containing both to only be removed so the result should be:

```
var arr= [
          {id: "123", name: "Bar"},
          {id: "345", name: "Foo"},
          {id: "678", name: "FooBar"}
         ];
```

Comment: Your `arr` variable declaration is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: please supply the correct data of `arr`. in this form it is not valid.

Comment: automatic semicolon insertion

Comment: I've corrected the `arr`

Comment: Unfortunately that's still broken. You can't have an array as the key of an object, and the `name` properties most likely need to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: There's obviously a bunch of code you're not showing us. Your filter function works correctly, provided the rest of the unshown code is also working correctly (which it undoubtedly isn't if you're not seeing your desired result)

Comment: If you really posted correct array, then `name: Foo` property refers to `Foo` variable or function, whereas you use it as **string** actually

Comment: `name: Foo` is a string in the `arr`

Comment: Please show the rest of your code. It's **not possible** for `return elem.id != id && elem.name != name;` to return false for all of your array elements unless each element has the same `name` and `id`. So the fact that you are getting all elements removed means that the piece of code that is broken is not being shown.

Comment: Not all the element for `arr` are removed, but all the elements that pass the 2 conditions. It's like the conditions are treated separately instead of together.

Comment: @CiprianD - think about that. It's just bad logic then. If `elem.id != id` is false (e.g. if the id's do match), then it won't evaluate the other side to check `elem.name != name`. You could change the `&&` to an `||` and it will work, although I think `return !(elem.id == id && elem.name == name)` is more readable.

Comment: @Adam Isn't that the purpose of `&&` to evaluate both arguments? If `elem.id != id` is false then it should leave that element in the `arr` but it didn't. For some reason your readability solution works. Thanks

Comment: @CiprianD - no the purpose of `&&` is to evaluate the right side only if the left side is true. If the left side is false, then the right side is never evaluated. Likewise, the purpose of `||` is to evaluate the right side only if the left side is false, which is why it works if you change the `&&` to `||`, if the id matches the given id (that is `elem.id != id` is false, meaning `elem.id == id`) then check compare the names and if `elem.name != name` is false (that is `elem.name == name` is true) then you've got a match. But you can see how convoluted that logic is to read and comprehend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more intuitive way to write that filter function would probably be like this:

```
var arr= [{id: "123", name: "Foo"},
          {id: "123", name: "Bar"},
          {id: "345", name: "Foo"},
          {id: "678", name: "FooBar"}
         ];

var name = 'Foo';
var id = '123';

arr = arr.filter(function(elem) {
  //return false for the element that matches both the name and the id
  return !(elem.id == id && elem.name == name)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to loop over an array of objects :

```
var arr = [
  {id: 123, name: Foo},
  {id: 123, name: Bar},
  {id: 345, name: Foo}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave comment until 50 rep but I'm guessing you've made a typo in your original post when declaring the array?

As a solution, could you change to:

```
elem.id === id && elem.name === name;
// and then remove the matching element from the array with .splice()?
```

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of `Array.prototype.filter` to do it this way, doesn't it?

Comment: @Adam I can't claim to be a JS guru so you could well be right and you could well be teaching me something here :)  I was just trying to provide an alternative for OP